# keymap swap underscore and dash

Tags: linux, keymap

I have noticed that when coding I type underscores much more often then dashes. Is it possible to swap these keycodes so I can type shiftless underscores? I am using linux (chromebook developer mode).

Comment: very similar question with an accepted answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised there wasn't more about this specific remapping out there, considering how popular snake_case is.

```
sudo xmodmap -e "keycode 20 = underscore minus underscore minus"
```

and to get back to normal:

```
sudo xmodmap -e "keycode 20 = minus underscore minus underscore"
```

For anyone wanting to map other keys, see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap

Basically, run `xmodmap -pke` to see what the keys are currently mapped to (it gives you the same format as the commands I wrote above), and use `xmodmap -e` to make your changes.