# Windows: swap underscore and dash key

Tags: windows, keyboard, remapping, sharpkeys

My question is the same as [keymap swap underscore and dash](https://superuser.com/questions/787508/keymap-swap-underscore-and-dash), but for Windows instead of Linux. How might I swap the dash `-` and underscore `_` keys so that underscore is shift-less?

I tried using [sharpkeys](/questions/tagged/sharpkeys) but it wouldn't let me use a chord, only single key press.

I also tried [powertoys](/questions/tagged/powertoys) [keyboard manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) Remap Shortcut, but it <s>wouldn't allow matching a chord with  a single key, both source and target have to be chords.</s> **Update:** it does allow swapping a chord with a single key, but not AND use the reverse at the same time.

**Update2**

This PT configuration only outputs dash:
[image: PT keyboard manager]

[image: can't select underscore]

It may well be that either program actually can do this but I failed to find the right path. At any rate, I need help. Any suggestions?

Keyboard layout is US-ANSI.

Comment: You could always try modifying keyboard manager yourself so it would allow cord with a single key, although, there might be an underline reason why it's not allowed. What is the error message when you attempt to do that (so I can look at the script).

Comment: @Ramhound there is no error message. I added screenshots.

Comment: If you are willing to modify the source and do the required debugging, you can modify the [source](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/tree/main/src/modules/keyboardmanager/KeyboardManagerEditor) of the editor, to list the underscore character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey V1](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

To swap <kbd>_</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>
you could use a AutoHotkey script such as:

```
$-::Send, _
$_::Send, -
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: That exact script didn't work for me, instead, I used this:
```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
$-::Send '_'
$_::Send '-'
```
Maybe it's a `v2.0` change? Either way, your answer is effectively right, but this might be helpful for others reaching this.

Side note: the `$` prevents the `Send` command from triggering the other swap

Comment: You're right, I modified the answer to add the forgotten "AutoHotkey V1".

Answer (score 0):

The [AutoHotkey V2](https://www.autohotkey.com/) version of the answer by @harrymc is:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
$-::Send '_' 
$_::Send '-'
```

I.e., add that to a `.ahk` script, and double-click it to load it into AutoHotkey.

Note: `$` prevents the `Send` command from triggering the other swap recursively.