# How to Swap Minus and Underscore Debian 11

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I used to use the method suggested in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/787508/keymap-swap-underscore-and-dash) for swapping minus and underscore on Ubuntu 16, namely:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 20 = underscore minus underscore minus"
```

This is not working for me on Debian 11. Is there another method that works?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye

$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
GNOME
```

This is the keyboard:
[image: keyboard]

Comment: What is your keyboard? Are minus and underscore found on the same one key?

Comment: @harrymc yes they are. It's a Reddragon k596

Comment: What is the actual keycode of the key? Try to get it from `xev`

Comment: What is the output of `echo "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE"`?

Answer (score 0):

The method you mentioned in your question works for me on Ubuntu 20.04.

However, you can try specifying `keysyms` instead of "minus" and "underscore" in your command, try if it works:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 20 = 0x5f 0x2d"
```

`0x2d` should be the keysym for "minus"  and `0x5f` should be "underscore".
You can check if this is true on your system with the `xev` command.

The first keysym in the command tells your system which key to execute when keycode 20 is pressed, and the second tells it what to execute when keycode 20 is pressed together with shift.

Answer (score 0):

**Option1**: directly edit the file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` for your layout. For example, it is `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`. Search for *minus*, find:
`key <AE11> {[ minus, underscore, quotedbl, plusminus ]}; // - _ " ±`
replace it with:
`key <AE11> {[ underscore, minus, quotedbl, plusminus ]}; // - _ " ±`
Logout, login.

**Option2**: use xkb
(according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65507/use-setxkbmap-to-swap-the-left-shift-and-left-control) unix.stackexchange answer by Pablo Saratxaga)

1. create a file `~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd` using:
   `setxkbmap -print > ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd`
2. create a file `~/.xkb/symbols/myswap` with the contents (assuming again that you need to edit AE11):
   `hidden partial alphanumeric_keys`
   `xkb_symbols "swap_minus_undersco" {`
       `key <AE11> {[ underscore, minus, quotedbl, plusminus ]};`
   `};`
3. edit the `~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd` file, and change the `xkb_symbols` line to add:
   `+myswap(swap_minus_undersco)`
4. load it:
   `xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd $DISPLAY`